# Why we write the constant in front of the Einstein-Hilbert Action?

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, conventions, dimensional-analysis, physical-constants

Why we write the constant?
$$S_{EH}=\frac{c^4}{16\pi G}\int \sqrt{-g}R d^4x$$

Comment: The question is too short.  Could you elaborate more?  What do you want to know?

Answer (score 4):

You need a constant with proper dimensions, because $\sqrt{-g} \;d^4 x \sim \mathrm{L}^4$ (an "hyper volume"), while $R \sim \mathrm{L}^{-2}$ (a "curvature").  Then, the integral has dimensions $\mathrm{L}^2$ (like an area).  Yet, the action shouldn't have any dimensions, in natural units (or if you set units such that $\hbar = 1$).  You then need a constant like $c^4 / G$.  The $16 \pi$ is a convention to simplify calculations and to get the Newton's gravitational constant in the non-relativistic limit.

It is usually much easier to use Planck's units, such that $c =1$, $\hbar = 1$, so $G \sim \mathrm{L}^2$ (the square of the Planck's length).

Also, it is much simpler to use $\kappa \equiv 8 \pi G / c^4 \sim \text{meters}/\text{joules}$ as the relativistic gravitational constant.  Thus:
$$\tag{1}
S_{\text{grav}} = \int_{\mathcal{M}} \frac{1}{2 \kappa} \,R \, \sqrt{-g} \; d^4 x \sim \mathrm{L}^0.
$$

From the comments:

Action has dimensions "energy" $\times$  "time".  It is the same in relativity (I don't add a $c$ factor yet).  We may divide the action by $\hbar \sim$ "energy" $\times$ "time" to get an unitless quantity, to simplify things.  So basically, action don't have units (thanks to QM !).  But then (in some cartesian-like coordinates):
$$\tag{2}
d^4 x = c \, dt \: dx \: dy \: dz \sim \mathrm{L}^4,
$$
and $R \sim \mathrm{L}^{-2}$.  So if you write
$$\tag{3}
S \propto \int R \, \sqrt{-g} \; d^4 x,
$$
you then need a factor to remove its $\mathrm{L}^2$ units.  The constant $\hbar G / c^3 \sim \mathrm{L}^2$ has it.  So we get:
$$\tag{4}
S = k \frac{c^3}{\hbar G} \int_{\mathcal{M}} R \, \sqrt{-g} \; c \, dt \: dx \: dy \: dz = k \frac{c^4}{\hbar G} \int_{\mathcal{M}} R \, \sqrt{-g} \; dt \: dx \: dy \: dz,
$$
where $k$ is an arbitrary unitless constant.  We prefer $k = \frac{1}{16 \pi}$ to recover Newton's theory in the non-relativistic limit.

Comment: Action unit=[energy]x[ time] when i write your unit analysis, i obtain joule x d(ct) it is [energy]x[time]x[c] . Energy x time is planck constant unit and h equal 1.  c=1 it is dimensionless. Do i understand it true ?

Comment: I added a few things in my answer.

Comment: Is there any reason, other than the needs of quantum mechanics, that the action must have units of energy*time?  At the classical level, multiplying the action by any constant (with any dimensions) yields an equivalent theory.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert, it is true that a classical action could have any unit.  However, all actions that we add together must have the same unit (obviously), and we could factor out a common factor (wathever its unit).  It's the *relative* constant from each action term that is physically meaningfull.  It's a good thing to define the action scalar as an unitless quantity all from the start, a bit like entropy (in units of Boltzmann's constant).  It just simplies things.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert *At the classical level, multiplying the action by any constant (with any dimensions) yields an equivalent theory.* I agree, yet all textbooks that I’ve seen make even classical “action” functionals have the dimensions of action. I assume that consistency with quantum mechanics, and Occam’s Razor, is the reason.

Comment: I like to think of the action as a measure of the "area" covered by a system in its phase space.  Very losely speaking :  in units of $\hbar$, it gives the number of "discernible classical states" swept by the system during its evolution.  In a way, it's a measure of the "mechanical information" that you need to recover the full history of the system.  This interpretation is very rough.  I don't know if this could be made more rigorous.

Comment: Actions having dimensions of Energy*time, long predates even the earliest thoughts about quantum mechanics. By definition an action is the time integral of a Lagrangian. Lagrangians have dimensions of Energy same as Hamiltonians. (This can be seen as following from Noether's theorem.)

Answer (score 4):

That particular multiplicative constant $c^4/16\pi G$ in the [Einstein-Hilbert gravitational action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93Hilbert_action) is necessary to produce the proper constants on the right side of the [Einstein field equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations),

$$R_{\mu\nu}-\frac12Rg_{\mu\nu}=\frac{8\pi G}{c^4}T_{\mu\nu},$$

when one varies the *complete* action

$$S=S_\text{EH}+S_\text{MR}$$

including a matter-and-radiation term $S_\text{MR}$ for which the [Hilbert energy-momentum tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor#Hilbert_stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor) is

$$T_{\mu\nu}=\frac{-2}{\sqrt{-g}}\frac{\delta S_\text{MR}}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}}.$$

The constants in the Einstein field equations are there to reduce to Newtonian gravitation in the weak-field limit.

The $c^4/G$ in the Einstein-Hilbert action is necessary simply on dimensional grounds to make it have the dimensions of action. But without considering how gravity couples to non-gravitational fields, one can’t explain the $1/16\pi$ in the Einstein-Hilbert action.